# How to use precompiled header in DLL with dependencies

Tags: c++, dll, linker, precompiled-headers

My situation: I'm writing DLL, it has many classes, but I export only one:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef APIDLL_EXPORTS
#define APIDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define APIDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class Process; // <-- ApiClient uses pointer to that class, so I forward declare it

class APIDLL_API ApiClient
{
    web::http::client::http_client client; // (*) line
public:
    void check(Process * p);
}
```

And In `ApiClient.cpp` I have `#include "pch.h"`, which is:

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

// add headers that you want to pre-compile here
#include "framework.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#include <cpprest/asyncrt_utils.h>

#endif //PCH_H
```

As it is compiling as DLL, it won't compile when I link it to console app. I put in `includes` directory `ApiClient.h` (because I export and need only this) (path to .lib is correct). I get error in (*) line `E0276 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name`. It looks like compiler can't see definition of `http_client`. So if I add `#include <cpprest/http_client.h>` in `ApiClient.h`, all is good.

But I'd like to have every needed dependency in 'pch.h'. Should I copy it to `includes` directory also? But what if I add some relative paths to pch.h?

Comment: The pch.h file shouldn't be a part of the equation. Make the header file that contains your interface include what *it* needs. You should be able to use the DLL in projects where pch.h doesn't even exist.

Comment: @TedLyngmo okay. In my case vcpkg integration made cpprestsdk library accessible everywhere. If I will send DLL to someone, should I also provide headers for that cpprestsdk? Or is there a way to compile it staticly?

Comment: You need to supply headers containing the classes/functions/enums etc that you want the users to use. Stuff that is only used internally in the DLL doesn't need to be included. The PCH.H files should definitely not be included in the package.

Comment: If someone needs to include a header to get declarations and definitions, they need the header. Do what you can  to hide what you don't want the client to see. Perhaps [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) may be of use to you.

Comment: Header files need to be self contained, that is have corresponding `#inlcude` for each symbol used. You also seem to misuse precompiled header. It is not a file to dump every needed dependency to, it is a file that includes third-party-rarely-changing headers included in other files in order to speedup compilation.

Comment: I turned off user-wide integration, so I haven't paths to cpprestsdk headers files, I'm trying to compile my DLL and I get error `cannot open source file "cpprest/http_client.h"` near `#include <cpprest/http_client.h>` :(. Should I add that includes after `__declspec(dllimport)` ?

Comment: Are you aware of how include files work in C++? Trying to build stuff with trial and error is not very productive...

Comment: Yea, I know. Ok, I have added in Additional Includes path to cppressdk headers files, it works now. I just thought that my lib could self include that files, nevermind, now is ok, thanks for help